# Edit attribute value and add new attribute in xml using python

Tags: python, xml

Below is the sample XML file consisting of 3 data-sources. In each data-source there is a  tag having an attribute .

Now, out of 3 data-sources, 2 of them didn't have the  attribute and one of the data-source have  but the value is false.

I want to add the  attribute in the missing one and modify its values to true in data-source where its present.

**SAMPLE XML snippets:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do not post images of source code, copy-paste the relevant code to your question. Also, please clarify what exactly you're having trouble with.

Comment: I cannot put the whole xml content but, following is the snippet I want to modify:

attribute 'use-fast-fail' value to true and similarly add this attribute inside <validation></validation> tag if its missing.

**<validation>**

  <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1 FROM dual</check-valid-connection-sql>
  <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
  <background-validation>false</background-validation>
  **<use-fast-fail>false</use-fast-fail>**
**</validation>**

Comment: apologies for formatting.

Comment: I tried to replace <use-fast-fail> value from false to true however, its not working. See below code:

#!/usr/bin/python

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with open("sample.xml", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
    tree = ET.parse(f)
    root = tree.getroot()

    for elem in root.findall('use-fast-fail'):
        try:
                elem.text = elem.text.replace('false', 'true')
        except AttributeError:
            pass

tree.write("output.xml", xml_declaration=True, method='xml', encoding="UTF-8")

Answer (score 0):

**Using DOM**

```
# import minidom
import xml.dom.minidom as mdom

# open with minidom parser
DOMtree = mdom.parse("Input.xml")
data_set = DOMtree.documentElement

# get all validation elements from data_Set
validations = data_set.getElementsByTagName("validation")

# read all validation from validations
for validation in validations:
    # get the element by tag anme
    use-fast-fail = validation.getElementsByTagName('use-fast-fail')
    # if the tag exist
    if use-fast-fail:
        if use-fast-fail[0].firstChild.nodeValue == "false":
            # if tag value is false replace with true
            use-fast-fail[0].firstChild.nodeValue = "true"
    # if tag does not exist add tag
    else:
        newTag = DOMtree.createElement("use-fast-fail")
        newTag.appendChild(DOMtree.createTextNode("true"))
        validation.appendChild(newTag)

# write into output file
with open("Output.xml", 'w') as output_xml:
   output_xml.write(DOMtree.toprettyxml())
```

**Using simple file read and string search with regex**

```
# import regex
import re

#open the input file with "read" option
input_file = open("intput.xml", "r")
#put content into a list
contents = input_file.readlines()
#close the file
input_file.close()

#loop to check the file line by line
#for every entry - get the index and value
for index, value in enumerate(contents):
    #searches the "value" contains attribute with false value
    if (re.search('<background-validation>false<background-validation/>',value)):
        #if condition true True - changes to desired value
        contents[index] = "<background-validation>true<background-validation/>\n"
    #searches the "value" contains attribute, which always comes just before the desired attribute
    if (re.search('validate-on-match',value)):
        #searches the "value" of next element in the list contains attribute
        if not (re.search('<background-validation>"',contents[index + 1])):
            #if not adding the attribute
            contents.insert(index + 1, "<background-validation>true<background-validation/>\n")

#open the file with "write" option
output_file = open("Output.xml", "w")
#joining all contents
contents = "".join(contents)
#write into output file
output_file.write(contents)
output_file.close()
```

**Note:** in the second options, addition of line if does not exist is given in an assumption that all data-source block is in same structure and order, else we may need to check multiple conditions.

Comment: @Parfait i just used it for string search, :)

Comment: @Parfait added solution with DOM too, :)